# How can I check a compressed file for reliability?

Tags: files, tar, compression

I have a 5GB folder with my research from last year. To save space, I compressed the folder, and all its contents. The compressed file `*.tar.xz`, is 761MB, which seems really tiny. That made me wonder:

How can I verify the contents of the compressed file against the uncompressed directory?  Is 761MB really correct? how can I know? Is there an easy way to figure that out? Or, is there something which will give me more details about the compression? ... As in something that might say: Your 5GB folder will 761MB using this compression type....

That information could be really handy to know. Right now, I am using options available for compression via the file manager, caja. I am using mate, Ubuntu 14.04.

command line options are fine too.

Comment: Although you could list the files and compare a list, IMO the only way to "test" the archive is to extract it and see.

Comment: Might it be that you have a lot of matrices in there? And many zeros, too? Imagine it this simple way: writing down "repeat 0.0000 'newline' for 1,000,000 times" is shorter than writing these millions of zeros out. I could compress data to 5-10% in many occasions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `-d` command. Quoting from [`man tar`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/tar.1):

```
-d, --diff, --compare
   find differences between archive and file system
```

This might be very time-consuming, though.

Example in action:

```
$ tar -Jcf bin.tar.xz bin
$ echo foo >> bin/login.sh 
$ tar -Jdf bin.tar.xz
bin/login.sh: Mod time differs
bin/login.sh: Size differs
```

---

> Or, is there something which will give me more details about the compression? ... As in something that might say: Your 5GB folder will 761MB using this compression type.

In general, the only way to know what size some data will compress to is to actually compress it.

`xz` is usually good at compression, and if most of your 5 GB was text, it could have compressed well (as opposed to, say PDF files or media files).